# Can I filter output from `tail` with the `-f` flag?

Tags: bash, rhel6, grep, pipe, tail

I'd like to `tail -f` the output of `access_log` on RHEL 6.8 but pipe and grep that output to act as a filter. Is there such an option?

That is I'd like live output from:

```
# tail -f error_log | grep <<ON.THIS.IP.ADDY>>
```

Currently I'm doing something akin to this, but it's clunky:

```
watch -n 5 'tail -n 10 access_log | grep <<ON.THIS.IP.ADDY>>'
```

Comment: Clunky? What's wrong with the first command?

Comment: The terminal would appear to 'hang' after the first command. The accepted answer below was all I needed. Adding `--line-buffered` solved all problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a `tail -f <nginx-access.log> | grep <ip>` and as expected new lines showed up regularly.

What happens when you try? Could it be hat your `grep` buffers  (I think i've seen that), in that case it might help to add `--line-buffered` to the `grep`.